# Cannot find ref on initial render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I just read in the official documents that componentDidUpdate isn't called on first render and I think maybe that's why dom isn't defined the first time this Component of mine is rendered.

This is a pop up modal that pops up when a page needs to be edited.

Is there any other way I can go about this?

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.renderSingularForm();
}

renderSingularForm() {
    let dom = ReactDOM.findDOMNode( this.refs.singularForm );
    if ( this.props.pageObjToEdit && dom ) {
        // DOESN'T GO HERE ON FIRST RENDER BECAUSE DOM IS NULL

        createForm( window, dom, this.props.pageObjToEdit );
    }
}

render() {
    if ( this.props.pageObjToEdit ) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div ref="singularForm" />
            </div>
        );
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with how you are using refs. You shouldn't be using string refs anymore since they [will be deprecated soon](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs). Most people are now using an inline ref ( `ref={ref => this.input = ref}` ), but when you do that, the first time the component renders it will receive a `null` value. Then on the second render, the refs will be correctly assigned with the DOM element.

To get around this, you should supply a class method to the `ref` prop instead of an inline function.

Example:

This:

```
render() {
    return (
        ...
        <div ref="singularForm" />
        ...
    )
}
```

Should be:

```
applyRef = ref => {
    this.singularForm = ref;
}
render() {
    return (
        ...
        <div ref={this.applyRef} />
        ...
    )
}
```

When you use a class method to apply a ref, it only gets called once when the actual element has been added to the dom, so you shouldn't get the initial `null` values anymore.

## **UPDATE 10/18:**

You can now avoid this problem altogether using the new [`React.createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) to create your refs.

Comment: ah i see.  thank you for that explanation.  let me re-read to understand better and let me try to apply

Comment: the example you gave didn't work, but once i get the concept of what you're saying i can probably apply it

Comment: it worked!  it took a while for me to wrap my head around the concept and understand but when i did it worked. ty again

Comment: hm actually it works but shortly after i get errors about not being able to access the actual element.. hm

Comment: okay i got it to work but it still doesn't load the very first time on render.. frustrating

Answer (score 1):

You can and should use the [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) in order to safely get DOM elements or refs

From the DOCS:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
> mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here.
> ...
>
> It can, however, be necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when
> you need to measure a DOM node before rendering something that depends
> on its size or position.

**Also Note** that you are using the [old ref API](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs).
You should use the new [ref API](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components)

Running Example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.myDiv.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="some-id" ref={ref => (this.myDiv = ref)}>some div</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: hm i tried componentDidMount earlier and just now.. but now the form won't generate.

Comment: i've update my answer regarding the ref issue you have

Comment: thank you for the update in answer.  reading the docs and looking at your example to understand further.