# REACT this.refs doesn't worked

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Please check this code :

I have a ref attribute in my render template and I would like to play with him for some actions, but for test I just console.log of him but he didn't worked

If you see on my code the `focusTextInput`method, I made a simply console.log of ref value.

```js
export default class Form extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this._createBounds();
    }

    _createBounds() {
        ['focusTextInput']
            .forEach((fn) => this[fn] = this[fn].bind(this));
    }

    static _getSkills() {
        return [
            {_id: 1, text: 'HTML'},
            {_id: 2, text: 'CSS'},
            {_id: 3, text: 'JavaScript'},
            {_id: 4, text: 'PHP'},
            {_id: 5, text: 'MYSQL'}
        ];
    }

    _renderSkills() {
        return Form._getSkills().map((skills) => (
            <Skills key={skills._id} content={skills.text}/>
        ));
    }


    /* THIS FUNCTION IS CALL WHEN ONCLICK IF FIRED */
    focusTextInput() {
        let val = this.refs.newText.value;
        console.log(val)
    }
    
    /* END */

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="header-form">
                <h2 className="header-form-title">Hello, please type informations about you</h2>
                <form className="form-container" action="#">
                    <div className="form-field">
                        <Input ref="newText" type='text' placeholder="Votre nom"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-field">
                        <Input type='text' placeholder="Votre prénom"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-field">
                        <Input type='text' placeholder="Votre âge"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-field">
                        <Input type='text' placeholder="Votre email"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-field">
                        <select className="form-field-select">
                            {this._renderSkills()}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-field submit">
                        <Input onClick={this.focusTextInput} type='submit' value="Envoyer"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This has to do with string refs. Check out my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584188/cannot-find-ref-on-initial-render/47584223#47584223

Comment: The only explanation of problem that expose, is deprecated soon ? 
Anyway, your answer on other post are correct for my problem, but I have a question, probably is an idiot question, so on your code : `this_singularity` 
it is a variable that is useless, apart from assigning ref ?

Comment: Yep, it's a class variable that's used to store a reference to the dom node.